# How to find texlive cygwin documentation

Tags: texlive, cygwin

This might be more of a Cygwin than Latex question, but I don't know.  Is there a convenient way to find and open the documentation for Latex packages within Cygwin?  The only way I could think of is to do a Windows search all of my Cywin install directory for pdfs, but I figure there must be a better way.  Is there?

Comment: If you use the TUG  texlive cygwin build (which is what I use) rather than the tex in the cygwin repository you can use `texdoc longtable` to get the (excellent!) longtable documentation. similarly any other package.

Comment: actually cygwin default tex may have texdoc in one of the extra packages I didn't check, but I don't have it in /usr/bin only in my texlive 2014 and 2015 installations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `texdoc` is the way. The binary is included in our cygwin builds, as one can check in the svn repo http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/i386-cygwin/

`texdoc` works practically out of the box, just call it with a package name or file name and in most cases will find documentation.

If you need more help with it, call `texdox texdoc`

Answer (score 0):

The search function in the Cygwin package manager doesn't find texdoc, so I bit the bullet and installed everying under publishing (i.e. Latex related) along with with all that bloat. Somewhere within all that jetsam and flotsam was the nugget I needed, namely texdoc.

After editing the texdoc config file and installing xpdf, It worked!